# PDF to HTML/Rich Text Document

Tags: python

I have a PDF file which is nothing but a legal contract which contains a lot of sections. The sections simply consist of section headings and section's contents. I want to somehow extract all the sections and headings into separate text files.

Text File 1: Heading 1 + Heading 1 content
Text File 2: Heading 2 + Heading 2 content

Thanks in advance...

I thought of converting my PDF to HTML file (with formatting) to somehow get the text arranged in heading, paragraph and lists tags but could not climb upto the solution. Any help would be very appreciable.

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

The utility you seek is creatively named `pdftohtml`.

```
$ brew info pdftohtml 
==> pdftohtml: stable 0.40a (bottled)
Utility which converts PDF files into HTML and XML formats
https://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/
```

A moment's googling reveals that numerous online services
are able to perform a similar action.

Once you have the text as HTML there's a whole world
of possibilities that opens up, including munging it with
[Beautiful Soup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4).